# python Split list based on delimiting list value

Tags: python, list

I've dug through countless other questions but none of them seem to work for me. I've also tried a ton of different things but I don't understand what I need to do. I don't know what else to do.

list:

```
split_me = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'list', '--', 'and', 'thats', 'what', 'it', 'is!', '--', 'Please', 'split', 'me', 'up.']
```

I need to:

- Split this into a new list everytime it finds a "--"
- name the list the first value after the "--"
- not include the "--" in the new lists.

So it becomes this:

```
this=['this', 'is', 'my', 'list']
and=['and', 'thats', 'what', 'it', 'is!']
please=['Please', 'split', 'me', 'up.']
```

current attempt (Work in progress):

```
for value in split_me:
    if firstrun:
        newlist=list(value)
        firstrun=False
        continue

    if value == "--":
        #restart? set firstrun to false?
        firstrun=False
        continue
    else:
        newlist.append(value)

print(newlist)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this got 3 downvotes so quickly, but it would certainly help if you showed what you tried. It's not too difficult with a `for` loop as a start.

Comment: Hey Dylan, the fact that you looked and couldn't find code that does exactly what you want is not surprising considering how specific is your use case. In order to post a good question you should try to solve your own problem first, so start by trying to come up with an algorithm that solves your problem and then try to implement it. If you'll run into a more specific issue during your implementation feel free to post it here. Right now it looks like you're asking other people to do your task for you, and it doesn't look good. Good luck!

Comment: AFAIK, you can't create a variable out of a string. Your best bet would probably be creating a dict with lists as values. `{ 'this': ['this', 'is', 'my', 'list'], 'and': ['and', 'thats', 'what', 'it', 'is'] }` etc.

Comment: @alfasin thank you. I've tried countless things but they are all horrible and don't even come close to working. I'm not sure where else to turn

Comment: You really would get a better reception if you showed your "best" attempt, even if it isn't working. At least then you show effort on your part and people can address, specifically, your misunderstanding.

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, thanks. I kept deleting and restarting because I'm just really fustrated right now and lost. I'll keep working on what I have

Comment: Just edit your question with what you tried that came close and narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Mangohero1 Yes, you can create variables out of strings: just add them to the global dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This more or less works, although I had to change words to solve the reserved word problem. (Bad idea to call a variable 'and').

```
split_me = ['This', 'is', 'my', 'list', '--', 'And', 'thats', 'what', 'it', 'is!', '--', 'Please', 'split', 'me', 'up.']

    retval = []
    actlist = []

    for e in split_me:
            if (e == '--'):
                    retval.append(actlist)
                    actlist = []
                    continue
            actlist.append(e)

    if len(actlist) != 0:
            retval.append(actlist)

    for l in retval:
            name = l[0]
            cmd = name + " = " + str(l)
            exec( cmd )

    print This
    print And
    print Please
```

Comment: Thank you Ronald, say this didnt need to be named based on values, and maybe like "list1" , "list2". Would this be a better approach? Or easier

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing `itertools.groupby()`:

```
dash = "--"
phrases = [list(y) for x, y in groupby(split_me, lambda z: z == dash) if not x]
```

Initialize a dict and map each list to the first word in that list:

```
myDict = {}
for phrase in phrases:
    myDict[phrase[0].lower()] = phrase
```

Which will output:

```
{'this': ['this', 'is', 'my', 'list]
 'and': ['and', 'thats', 'what', 'it', 'is!']
 'please': ['Please', 'split', 'me', 'up.'] }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will actually create global variables named the way you want them to be named. Unfortunately it will not work for Python keywords such as `and` and for this reason I am replacing `'and'` with `'And'`:

```
split_me = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'list', '--', 'And', 'thats', 'what', 'it',
'is!', '--', 'Please', 'split', 'me', 'up.']       

new = True
while split_me:
    current = split_me.pop(0)
    if current == '--':
        new = True
        continue
    if new:
        globals()[current] = [current]
        newname = current
        new = False
        continue
    globals()[newname].append(current)
```

A more elegant approach based on @Mangohero1 answer would be:

```
from itertools import groupby
dash = '--'
phrases = [list(y) for x, y in groupby(split_me, lambda z: z == dash) if not x]
for l in phrases:
    if not l:
        continue
    globals()[l[0]] = l
```

Comment: Oh that's what you meant. I didn't know that was possible. Thanks, UV'd

Answer (score 1):

I would try something ike

```
" ".join(split_me).split(' -- ') # as a start
```

Comment: If I ditch the idea of naming the variables the first value, this is the quickest way I guess. just need to add for row in range(len(split_me)):
    print(split_me[row].split(" ")). Thanks for you answer FreshPow.